# How to edit all selected rows of ultragrid

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ultrawingrid

I have used a ultragrid in my windows application to show records of a table of my database by set its DataSource property to the datatable that returns from that table.

the number of rows can be about 100000 rows.

Now i have 2 questions:

1) I want to let user to select several rows of this grid and then edit them all.to do this i need to know which cells of these selected rows have same values and which of them have not and then show the same columns in a form.

the first solution i thought about, was check all columns of all selected rows through 2 foreach loop.Is there any better solution for this??

2)finally when the user press save button, the updates should apply on the table.what is the best way to do this??? (Use `IN` command or UpdateCommand of sqldataadapter or ...)

Comment: 'same value' cells throughout a row or a column?

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi please can you tell me what version of UltraGrid you are using becuase it is possible that the version you are using does not support MultiRow selection or editing

Comment: @Nero,I mean throughout a column in all selected rows.

Comment: @HatSoft,I have used Net Advantage 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution for my first question so i have used loop to compare all selected rows of my grid and diagnose the common values.
but i have used SqlBulkCopy for my second question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the UltraGrid provided method call UpdateData() to update all the multiple rows with  out need to track changes row by row or by cell

The [UpdateData method](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase~UpdateData.html) updates any modified information in the grid, sending it to the data provider. When the update is complete, any rows that were marked as having modified data will have that mark cleared.

The UpdateMethod needs to exit from cells that are still in edit mode, this is a bug and to resolve it you will need to use it as shown below

ultraGrid1.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode);
ultraGrid1.UpdateData();

More details on why to use it this way can be found here http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=4220

To answer you 2nd question you will have to use the UpdateData method this way

```
e.g.
private void ultraButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ultraGrid1.UpdateData();
    this.dbRowsTableAdapter.Update(this.testDataSet);
    ultraButton1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Again it seems UltraGrid keeps its local data pure to itself hence you will have to call the Update method of the TableAdapter, which means you will have to create a DataSet and fill it with the SqlDataAdapter.

Please see forum explaining clearly why UltraGrid.UpdateData method does not commit back to database here http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/57161.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but i think i could not ask my question in correct format...The user can not modified the data in the grid.he can just select several rows from grid and then by pressing edit button the edit form will open that should show the same values of those selected rows in the related textboxes and other textboxes should be empty.then the user can modified these textboxes and when he press Save button the information should save for all selected rows.

Comment: I mean something like what visual studio doing when you select several controls of a form, so if you look at properties panel you can see that the same properties of your selected controls has value but the other properties are empty.I hope i could say my meaning and excuse me if my english is poor.

Answer (score 3):

According to my analysis,

1) you can do the grouping in the ultragrid based on which all columns you want to see and save the data. After grouping the similar columns would appear together and it will save a lot of time in data analysis and figuring out which column data are same in different rows. Once you have got the list of similar data you vcan handle them easily through for each loop or even for loop as you would be able to access the count of rows thus generated.

2) You should look at using the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy for this. Here's the documentation, and of course there are plenty of tutorials online.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx
One should avoid IN when no. of records are more as it affects the performance. If you dont want to use sqlbulkcopy, then you can also go for UpdateData() of ultragrid(very useful feature of ultragrid)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i do not think grouping the columns can be useful for me.please see my comment for @HatSoft.